# Guice: Using injected class as local variable in default constructor

Tags: java, guice, xtend

I have a Java class in a xtend file that uses Guice, like this:

```
class myClass {
  @Inject private extension classA
  @Inject private extension classB

  // methods
  // ...
}
```

I want to add an integer field and modify the default constructor to set it by using a helper class IdProvider, doing something like this:

```
import some.package.IdProvider

class myClass {
  @Inject private extension classA
  @Inject private extension classB

  private long mMaxId

  new() {
    var IdProvider provider
    mMaxId = provider.getMaxId("Student")
  }

  // methods
  // ...
}
```

However this doens't work, I get this error:

*com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors.
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException*

I have also tried this, but I get the same error:

```
import some.package.IdProvider

class myClass {
  @Inject private extension classA
  @Inject private extension classB

  private long mMaxId
  @Inject private IdProvider provider

  new() {
    mMaxId = provider.getMaxId("Student")
  }

  // methods
  // ...
}
```

I am new to xtend and Guice, so any help understanding how to get this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer to this. I tracked the origin of the error to the constructor of IdProvider. In its constructor, it gets a file using getResource() like so:

```
URL theResource = getClass().getResource("aFile.txt");
File aFile = new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(theResource).getPath());
```

I found [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=219645) with the same error message as I am seeing. My  understanding is that FileLocator will work if you use Eclipse, but not if the code/tests are run from the command line (which is what I am doing).

I have changed the way I get the resource to this:

```
InputStream theResource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("aFile.txt");
```

and the error has gone away, so I think Guice/xtend had nothing to do with it.